# Is there any editor which popup defination of declared variable deepinside in code

Tags: editor, sublimetext, atom-editor, vi, gedit

I have a big Fortran code with more than a hundred declared real variables. When I go through the code, I cannot followup what was the declaration of different variables. Every time I have to go to top to see the meaning of pseudoname of the variable.
i.e.

In beginning of code,

```
real*8  fij(3,3)   !deformation gradient
```

Then after 1000 lines same variable comes like

```
a= fij * 0.3
```

Is there any free editor which quickly show `fij -> !deformation gradient` by moving mouse over `fij`?